# Android: como agrupar botões?

Tags: android

Olá,
na minha aplicação tenho um `textview` com uma pergunta e tenho depois 3 botões que são as opções possiveis para a resposta.

Alguém me sabe dizer como posso agrupar estes 3 botões para ter uma especie de Group Buttons, há alguma forma de fazer isto?
(se fossem radio buttons utilizaria `RadioGroup` como container, mas para botões normais há alguma forma de o fazer?)

Obrigada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há um componente que faça isso para você semelhante ao `RadioGroup`. Você precisara fazer isto via código, algo como:

```
...
firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeButtonState(true, false, false);
        }
});
secondButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeButtonState(false, true, false);
        }
});

thirdButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeButtonState(false, false, true);
        }
});
...
```

E para alterar o estado do seu `Button`:

```
private void changeButtonState(boolean first, boolean second, boolean third) {
    // caso você queira alterar a cor do botao selecionado
    if (first) {
        firstButton.setColorFilter(R.color.yourColor);
        secondButton.setColorFilter(R.color.yourColor2);
        thirdButton.setColorFilter(R.color.yourColor2);
    } else if (second) {
        firstButton.setColorFilter(R.color.yourColor2);
        secondButton.setColorFilter(R.color.yourColor);
        thirdButton.setColorFilter(R.color.yourColor2);
    } else {
        firstButton.setColorFilter(R.color.yourColor2);
        iBtnRatingMedium.setColorFilter(R.color.yourColor2);
        thirdButton.setColorFilter(R.color.yourColor);
    }

    firstButton.setSelected(first);
    secondButton.setSelected(second);
    thirdButton.setSelected(third);
}
```

Comment: Obrigada!..uma pergunta, o "setOnClickListener" onde o colocarias? Dentro do OnCreate()?

Comment: @porthfind isso, logo apos instanciar seus componentes

Comment: Eu coloquei no xml o comando android:onClick="onClick" em cada botão e dp no Java tenho la um metodo onClick...n sei se é mt correcto fazer assim, mas não acho correcto meter no onCreate()